# Python - convert SEGY to image/list of numbers, mark horizons, convert to SEGY

Tags: python, physics, geo, petrel

Ideally Python would be used.

My aim is to convert a SEGY (geology) file to an image or a list of numbers at each offset. I would get pixel data from OpenCV2. I would then use Python to mark horizons (interfaces between rock layers). I would then convert it back to SEGY and put it in Petrel.

I have tried:

- SegPy - "Assigned value 34907 for sweep_frequency_at_end attribute must be convertible to NNInt16: NNInt16 value 34907 outside range 0 to 32767"
- SegyIO - don't know how to get offset and shotpoint data from dataset
- Obspy - "cannot find module", even after pip, conda and easy install

I have tried free SEGY readers 
http://www.epgeology.com/other-software-f30/free-segy-viewers-t556.html

- SeiSee - entire section filled with a block of colour - not helpful
- SEGY detective - cannot view the image itself
- SEISVU - cannot find it available for download
- GSEGYview - it opens it but it's a bit unwieldly

Please advise.

I know it's off topic, but why is something as simple as an image/bunch of lines so difficult to process?

Comment: Maybe it's not difficult, please show your code, so we can maybe see whats going wrong

Comment: Did you found any library to covert it back to SEGY???

Comment: Nope! Sorry! I'm working directly in AI now!